# Android DDMS - send calls to actual device

Tags: android, telephony, ddms

Does anyone know how (or if it's possible) to simulate a call to an actual device (i.e. USB debugging) using the DDMS in eclipse? I have no problems simulating calls to the emulator and the app I'm writing runs fine in both the emulator or the device.

Platforms:
IDE: eclipse on a mac
Android Device: droid incredible, usb debugging enabled
other: `<application android:debuggable="true">`

---

figured out you can't call an actual device from the emulator.

Answer (score -2):

In the DDMS view, you have a tab called Emulator Control . You can set Incoming Number in here and call.

Comment: In DDMS view Telephony Action section is disable,so i cannot enter a number... how to do it.

Comment: @Sam Not sure why this is downvoted. Anyway... When you are running the application, the telephony action will be disabled. Also check if you manifest has right permissions.

Comment: for anybody stumbling about this (like i did). it is not possible to simulate that on the device. you need a SIM.