# Simulating phone call on real device

Tags: android, ddms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android DDMS - send calls to actual device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665164/android-ddms-send-calls-to-actual-device)

any ideas how to be able to simulate phone call on a real device (HTC desire), through the DDMS? The emulator is to slow, and i need to use the accelerometer.

I have searched on the internet and came up with nothing... My phone is connected properly (judging form the fact that i can use logcat).

Thanks!

Comment: whats the relation between phone call and accelerometer?

Comment: A change in phone state would trigger a service which would record motion. The emulator is static so no exciting data is coming from there...

Comment: found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4665164/628918
too bad there is no such option